# org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException:Connection to http://172.20.38.143 refused

Tags: android, json, client-server, localhost, client-side

I have developed client server Application .**I am accessing mysql with php running on my machine and client running on my cell which is connected to machine.WI-FI is also switched ON.**

**Internet Permission are also added in Manifest file** but then also the i encounter error

**172.20.38.143 is IP OF MY MACHINE**

```
  06-01 13:20:10.391: W/System.err(11157): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://172.20.38.143 refused
06-01 13:20:10.401: W/System.err(11157):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
06-01 13:20:10.401: W/System.err(11157):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
06-01 13:20:10.401: W/System.err(11157):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
06-01 13:20:10.401: W/System.err(11157):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
06-01 13:20:10.401: W/System.err(11157):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:674)
06-01 13:20:10.401: W/System.err(11157):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:511)
06-01 13:20:10.401: W/System.err(11157):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:489)
06-01 13:20:10.401: W/System.err(11157):    at nineandroid.net.example.library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:42)
06-01 13:20:10.401: W/System.err(11157):    at nineandroid.net.example.library.UserFunctions.registerUser(UserFunctions.java:59)
06-01 13:20:10.401: W/System.err(11157):    at nineandroid.net.example.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:52)
06-01 13:20:10.411: W/System.err(11157):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3567)
06-01 13:20:10.411: W/System.err(11157):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14224)
06-01 13:20:10.411: W/System.err(11157):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-01 13:20:10.411: W/System.err(11157):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-01 13:20:10.411: W/System.err(11157):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-01 13:20:10.411: W/System.err(11157):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
06-01 13:20:10.411: W/System.err(11157):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-01 13:20:10.411: W/System.err(11157):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-01 13:20:10.411: W/System.err(11157):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
06-01 13:20:10.421: W/System.err(11157):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
06-01 13:20:10.421: W/System.err(11157):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-01 13:20:10.421: W/System.err(11157): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /172.20.38.143 (port 80): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
06-01 13:20:10.431: W/System.err(11157):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
06-01 13:20:10.431: W/System.err(11157):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
06-01 13:20:10.431: W/System.err(11157):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
06-01 13:20:10.431: W/System.err(11157):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:848)
06-01 13:20:10.431: W/System.err(11157):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
06-01 13:20:10.431: W/System.err(11157):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
06-01 13:20:10.431: W/System.err(11157):    ... 20 more
06-01 13:20:10.431: W/System.err(11157): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
06-01 13:20:10.441: W/System.err(11157):    at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
06-01 13:20:10.441: W/System.err(11157):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
06-01 13:20:10.441: W/System.err(11157):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
06-01 13:20:10.441: W/System.err(11157):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
06-01 13:20:10.441: W/System.err(11157):    ... 25 more
06-01 13:20:10.441: E/Buffer Error(11157): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
06-01 13:20:10.451: E/JSON Parser(11157): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
06-01 13:20:10.451: D/AndroidRuntime(11157): Shutting down VM
06-01 13:20:10.451: W/dalvikvm(11157): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c0aa68)
06-01 13:20:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(11157): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-01 13:20:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(11157): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-01 13:20:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(11157):    at nineandroid.net.example.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:56)
06-01 13:20:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(11157):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3567)
06-01 13:20:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(11157):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14224)
06-01 13:20:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(11157):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-01 13:20:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(11157):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-01 13:20:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(11157):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-01 13:20:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(11157):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
06-01 13:20:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(11157):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-01 13:20:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(11157):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-01 13:20:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(11157):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
06-01 13:20:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(11157):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
06-01 13:20:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(11157):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**UserFunctions.java** to call jsonParser

```
public class UserFunctions {

private JSONParser jsonParser;

private static String loginURL = "http://172.20.38.143/ah_login_api/";
private static String registerURL = "http://172.20.38.143/ah_login_api/";

private static String login_tag = "login";
private static String register_tag = "register";

// constructor
public UserFunctions(){
    jsonParser = new JSONParser();
}

/**
 * function make Login Request
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * */
public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
    // return json
    // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
    return json;
}

/**
 * function make Login Request
 * @param name
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * */
public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

    // getting JSON Object
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
    // return json
    return json;
}

/**
 * Function get Login status
 * */
public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    int count = db.getRowCount();
    if(count > 0){
        // user logged in
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Function to logout user
 * Reset Database
 * */
public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    db.resetTables();
    return true;
}
}
```

**jsonParser.java**

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

**RegisterActivity.java**

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnRegister;
Button btnLinkToLogin;
EditText inputFullName;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
TextView registerErrorMsg;

// JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);
    registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);

    // Register Button Click event
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, password);

            // check for login response
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully registred
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        
                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);
                        // Close Registration Screen
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        // Error in registration
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    // Link to Login Screen
    btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // Close Registration View
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: post ur RegisterActivity.java?

Comment: Major reasons of this problem: 1. Your server is not running on the dedicated port 2. Server side firewall is ON. 3. Your client device does not have proper internet access.

Comment: thanks problem of refuses is solved...actually my antivirus was blocking

Comment: For me it was that my tablet's wifi was too weak to connect to the router, even though my laptop was solidly connected.

The tablet even showed it was connected to wifi but it couldn't even ping the router.

Comment: Try to `Ping 172.20.38.143` , maybe your device and server are not in the same LAN

Answer (score 0):

Check your emulator proxy settings PATH  Settings>Wireless and Networks > Look for Mobile networks > APN in that add new APN as per your domain Proxy.